# Load files from WEB-INF/wsdl/Schemas/Messages/ directory to class path in jboss eap 6.4

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I am migrating my application from jboss eap 5.1 to 6.4.
There are some xsd files I have kept in `WEB-INF/wsdl/Schemas/Messages/` folder. and in my code I am trying to retrieve the file using following logic:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/../wsdl/Schemas/Messages/MsgSearchDetails.xsd").
```

In jboss eap 5.1 it works fine but in 6.4 I am not able to get the file on this path. 
I know that jboss eap 6.4 loads file from `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB_INF/lib` directory in classpath.

So how can I read xsd files from  `WEB-INF/wsdl/Schemas/Messages/` folder in jboss eap 6.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all xsd files in a module folder in `JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/your-module/main` and define a module.xml here like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="your-module">
 <resources>
<!-- Modules -->
<resource-root path="."/>
</resources>
</module>
```

Add this module as a dependency to your WAR in a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and get it like this then:

> Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MsgSearchDetails.xsd")

Comment: Thanks Sampada.
I resolve this issue by moving all my xsds to src/main/resources folder of maven projects. So automatically it is now awailable inside classes folder inside war.